# Prove that the set of all fixed points is a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Let $A$ be a $n$-dimensional affine space ($ 2 \leq n$) and let $\Phi:A\to A$ be a bijective affine mapping, which isn't the identity mapping, with the following property:

For all points $p$ and $q$ in $A$ such that $p \neq \Phi(p)$ and $q \neq \Phi(q)$ we have that the line connecting $p$ and $\Phi(p)$ is parallel to the line connecting $q$ and $\Phi(q)$.

Prove that if $\Phi$ has a fixed point, then the set of all fixed points is a hyperplane.

My attempt:

$\Phi$ is a mapping of the form $\Phi:x \mapsto Mx + b$ where $M$ is an invertible matrix and $b$ some translation vector. By a change of coordinates, we may choose the fixed point of $\Phi$ as our origin. Then $\Phi$ takes the form of a linear mapping $\Phi:x \mapsto Mx$.
So then $x$ is a fixed point of $\Phi \iff Mx = x \iff (M-I)x=0 \iff x \in \ker(M-I) \iff x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. The claim then is equivalent to the claim that the eigenspace of $M$ for the eigenvalue $1$ has dimension $n-1$.

I don't know how to proceed or if I'm on the right track. I appreciate any hints or alternative soltuions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to notice that $\Phi$ can be the identical map, for which The set of fixed points is not a hyperplane. So I think that your exercise is in some sense incomplete.

However, supposing $\Phi \neq id_A$ gives us no problems. So, let's proceed.

You didn't use your hypothesis on $\Phi$. It is equivalent on saying that for all points $v,w$ you have that $v- \Phi (v), w- \Phi (w)$ are linearly dependent.

Notice that, from $\Phi \neq id_A$, you have that $M-I \neq 0$, so $\dim \ker (M-I) \leq n-1$ . We have to prove that in fact equality holds.

Now, from your hypothesis you have that $\dim \mbox{ Im } (M-I) \leq 1$.

And now
$$ n= \dim \ker (M-I) + \dim \mbox{ Im } (M-I) \leq n-1 + 1 = n$$
so equality must hold.

Comment: You're right of course! It was mentioned as well that $\Phi$ is not the identity map. I will edit my question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain more why $\dim \mbox{ Im } (M-I) \leq 1$ ?

Comment: Because $\forall v,w$ you have that $(M-I)v, (M-I)w$ are linearly dependent. This condition implies that inside the image of $M-I$ you cannot find two linearly independent vectors, i.e. any basis of $M-I$ has at most one element.